# Where does PouchDB store its data on a laptop?

Tags: firefox, ionic2, pouchdb

I have an ionic project I am testing via `ionic serve -lab` in Firefox on my laptop.

This project uses PouchDB for a local database. To test my App I need to clear the database but clearing all private data in Firefox does not do this.

If I know where PouchDB stores its data maybe I can delete the appropriate file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database adapter chosen can be found in the debugging data of [`db.info()`](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#database_information):

[image]

Then how you delete databases in the chosen adapter will vary with your JS runtime, i.e. in chrome:

[image]

newer versions of firefox have a very similar developer tools that look something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector).